# How can I parse data from a UIViewController having 2 CollectionViews with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pass-data

How do I parse data from a UIViewController having 2 different UICollectionViews? I have 2 UICollectionViews in on UIViewController.

I have tired this using didSelectItemAt and performSegue but it can't parse the data to the other screen

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLineup" {
        
            
        let gidilecekShowVC = segue.destination as! lineupViewerVC
        
        gidilecekShowVC.showLineup = selectLineup1
       
    } else if segue.identifier == "showLineup2" {
        
        let gidilecekShowVC = segue.destination as! lineupViewer2VC
        
        gidilecekShowVC.showLineup2 = selectLineup2
       
    }
}
```

I know didSelectItemAt is wrong, but I don't know what the correct one is.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    selectLineup1 = ekranaYansitA1[indexPath.item]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLineup", sender: nil)
    
    selectLineup2 = ekranaYansitA2[indexPath.item]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLineup2", sender: nil)
  
}
```

I'm a beginner. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didSelectItemAt` has a `collectionView` parameter which gives you the collection view instance which triggered the method.

Assuming you have an `IBOutlet` named `lineup1CollectionView`, a reference to the first collection view you can perform a check

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if collectionView == lineup1CollectionView {
        selectLineup1 = ekranaYansitA1[indexPath.item]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLineup", sender: nil)
    } else {
        selectLineup2 = ekranaYansitA2[indexPath.item]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLineup2", sender: nil)
    }
}
```